# Connecting cassandra cluster through scala

Tags: scala, playframework, cassandra

I am new in both scala and cassandra . I know the connectivity of cassandra with java using hector . But I don't know how to connect cassandra through scala. I want a simple example for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some Scala projects that arose to support Cassandra connectivity, including [cassie](https://github.com/twitter/cassie) by Twitter, but they all seemed to die off.

Since you know Hector, if you have the Hector jars in your classpath, you can simply use the Hector API in Scala if you prefer.

For example, borrowing from the [documentation](http://hector-client.github.io/hector/build/html/content/getting_started.html#accessing-data), you could just do this:

```
val myCluster = HFactory.getOrCreateCluster("test-cluster","localhost:9160")
```

or

```
val template = new ThriftColumnFamilyTemplate[String, String](ksp, columnFamily, StringSerializer.get(), StringSerializer.get())
```

I wrote this freehand, so the syntax might be off, but you get the idea.

Comment: This is bad advice.  You should use the native Java driver as suggested by @kfer38.

Comment: Telling someone to add tabasco sauce to an ice cream sundae is "bad advice." You missed the broader point, which was that you can incorporate any Java API using Scala syntax (as opposed to an API built with Scala), and I gave Hector as an example because of the OP's experience. Kudos to @kfer38 for coming up with another example of my point. How the Datastax driver compares to Hector as a Cassandra client is beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: Perhaps "bad advice" is too strong.  In your defense he did ask specifically about Hector.  However it's also clear (from the fact that he is using Scala to access Cassandra for the first time) that he is writing new code, in which case it would be ill-advised to use an effectively deprecated library.  The native Java library should be considered the only valid JVM-based option at this point.

Comment: As I write this today, the last changes to Hector were made 17 days ago to the test directory and a month ago to the src directory: https://github.com/hector-client/hector. That hardly sounds "deprecated" to me. Regardless, your point about the currency of Hector is off-topic. I will leave it to the judgment of the OP to decide which library is best suited to his needs. I can only imagine what one must endure when he asks you, "Want to try the new sushi place for dinner?" and your response devolves into the nutritional value of white rice vs. brown rice.

Comment: I am using Play! 2.4 framework and Cassandra 2.2 version. I am also unable to  connect Cassandra from my code. I am using Kundera 3.2 library dependency in my application for connecting through Kundera. But still am unable to connect cassandra db from my application. If anyone can help regarding proper configuration for Kundera in Play! framework and making necessary changes in either build.sbt file or persistence.xml file ? The error I am getting is
`com.impetus.kundera.KunderaException: All hosts are down. please check servers manully.` Please help!!!

Answer (score 5):

I am using the datastax java driver. It's development is still active on github. I looked at Hector earlier but it seemed dying. The doc here's helpful: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/1.0/webhelp/index.html#java-driver/quick_start/qsQuickstart_c.html. I translated the first example to scala. Also, look at the akka-cassandra example from typesafe activator. Cheers.

```
object Hello extends App {

  import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;
  import com.datastax.driver.core.Host;
  import com.datastax.driver.core.Metadata;
  import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

  var cluster: Cluster = null
  private var session: Session = null

  def connect(node: String) {
    cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(node).build()
    val metadata = cluster.getMetadata()
    printf("Connected to cluster: %s\n",
      metadata.getClusterName())
    metadata.getAllHosts() map {
      case host =>
        printf("Datatacenter: %s; Host: %s; Rack: %s\n",
          host.getDatacenter(), host.getAddress(), host.getRack())
    }
  }

  def close() {
    cluster.shutdown()
  }

  this.connect("127.0.0.1");
  this.close();
}
```

Comment: can you tell me the library dependencies which i have to put in sbt file.

Comment: `libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.cassandra" % "cassandra-driver-core" % "1.0.4"`

Comment: i am getting error that - "Unable to find abstract-type class 'org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimestampType'] "

Comment: @Jagveer I'm using the latest driver posted on the github page `"com.datastax.cassandra" % "cassandra-driver-core" % "2.0.0-beta2"`. It compiles without a problem. This line ` private var session: Session = null` needs to removed else you have to import Session. It was left from transcribing part 2 of the driver example.

Comment: yeh! my problem is solved .. now i am using datastax drivers but its speed of retrieving the records is very slow approx 10 times than using hector...

Answer (score 2):

I've been working on Scala wrapper of Java Driver to minimize boilerplate code. You could find it here:
https://github.com/InnovaCo/binders-cassandra

Here is an example of class that works with some Cassandra DB:

```
class Db(session: com.datastax.driver.core.Session) {

  implicit val cache = new SessionQueryCache[PlainConverter](session)

  // class for binding input/output parameters
  case class User(userId: Int, name: String)

  def insertUser(user: User): Future[Unit] = cql"insert into users(userid, name) values (?, ?)".bind(user).execute

  // returns Future[Iterator[User]]
  def selectAllUsers: Future[Iterator[User]] = cql"select * from users".all[User]

  // if no user is found will throw NoRowsSelectedException
  def selectUser(userId: Int) = cql"select * from users where userId = $userId".one[User]

  // if no user is found will return None, otherwise Some(User)
  def selectUserIfFound(userId: Int) = cql"select * from users where userId = $userId".oneOption[User]
}
```

To use library in your playframework project, add this line to the build.sbt file:

```
libraryDependencies += "eu.inn" %% "binders-cassandra" % "0.2.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

## Datastax Driver 3 Scala Integration

I have found some articles [(example)](https://www.beyondthelines.net/databases/querying-cassandra-from-scala/) 
and [Maga library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23587404/1549135)
showing how you could integrate Java Driver better with Scala and it did not look hard.

**The result is my own library that you can find on GitHub: https://github.com/atais/scassandra**

It allows for seamless integration in Scala for both `CQL` queries and manipulating the `ListenableFuture` without mapping it into `scala.Future`.

```
implicit protected val session: com.datastax.driver.core.Session
implicit protected val executor: java.util.concurrent.Executor

val selectCQL: ListenableFuture[PreparedStatement] = cql"SELECT * FROM $table WHERE key = ?"
val result: ListenableFuture[ResultSet] = execute(selectCQL, "my-key")

result.map(rs => rs.one())
      .map(...)
```

Enjoy :)